# Ajuda armazenamento em arquivo XML

Tags: banco-de-dados, xml

boa tarde!

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para cadastro de produtos. No entanto, estou pensando em criar um arquivo XML para armazenar as características gerais dos produtos (as demais informações ficarão no banco de dados), pois cada produto possui seus atributos específicos. A estrutura ficaria +/- assim:

```html
<produto id="1">
   <atributo>Editora</atributo>
   <decricao>Globo</descricao>
</produto>

<produto id="2">
   <atributo>Altura</atributo>
   <decricao>1,65m</descricao>
   <atributo>Largura</atributo>
   <decricao>5,00m</descricao>
   <atributo>Material</atributo>
   <decricao>Sucupira</descricao>
</produto>
```

O problema é que a quantidade de produtos cadastrados será enorme (acredito que milhares)! Assim esse arquivo xml vai ficar muito grande.

Gostaria de saber de vocês se é viável o uso de um arquivo XML para esse propósito. E se também é possível utilizá-lo juntamente com um SGBD para facilitar a busca dentro desse arquivo.

Obrigado,
André

Comment: Cara, pelo que você descreveu o ideal seria fazer tudo usando um SGBD, o ideal é trabalhar com arquivos apenas se pretende trocar dados com algum outro sistema.

Answer (score 4):

Armazene as informações no SGBD, arquivos XML são úteis para armazenar
configurações ou transportar dados via WebService.

Se você não estiver criando uma API para ser consumida, não precisará do XML.

Quanto a questão relacionada a performance, deve-se medir antes o desempenho 
para melhor avaliar os pontos de melhora. Esta etapa deve vir quando a aplicação estiver pronta. Você pode otimizar as consultas SQL e criar índices nas tabelas do banco, ou ainda fazer uso de cache de memória. Nunca utilize um arquivo como banco de dados.